# vb.net DataGridView column alignment

Tags: vb.net

Here is what is happening I have a DataGridView called `dtgQue` when I go to add columns there are coming in on right side and not on the left where my other two DataGridViews come in is there a setting where I can make it so the columns start on the left like they should be? I am not talking about the text with in the box's. The whole columns start on the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `DisplayIndex` of your Column.

```
dtgQue.Columns("MyColumnName").DisplayIndex = 0 'This will set the column at first position
```

or use like this

```
myColumn.DisplayIndex = 0
```

Thus, you can set the order of all columns. You can set this property from design mode also.

**EDITED:**

if the all columns directions are started from right side then you need to check `RightToLeft` property. It should be set to `No`.

Comment: No like its not the order like the whole grid starts from the Right and adds to the left

Comment: Why is my columns adding Right to left though it is Left To light on the other.

Comment: check the RightToLeft property of your grid. It should be `No`

Comment: It's Set to No. I don't get why this one is different from my other Two I just Copyed them.